# Mongoose return documents created before a particular month

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mern

I am trying to get users who registered before a particular month:

```
const getUsersWhoRegisteredBeforeAGivenMonth = async (month, year) => {
  const project_stage = {
    $project: {
      year: { $year: "$date" },
      month: { $month: "$date" },
    },
  };

  const filter_stage = {
    $match: {
      year: {
        $lte: parseInt(year),
      },
      month: {
        $lte: parseInt(month),
      },
    },
  };

  const pipeline = [project_stage, filter_stage];
  const users = await User.aggregate(pipeline);
  return users;
};
```

But, this returns the wrong results.
When `month = 1` and `year = 2022`, instead of returning all the documents created before ***01/2022***, it returns the documents created from the **beginning of 2022** until the end of ***01/2022*** and the documents created from the **beginning of 2021** until the end of ***01/2021***.
And if I pick ***02/2022***, it will do the same thing until the end of ***02/2022*** and ***01/2021***.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Any reason why you cannot filter by date? `{date: {$lt:ISODate("2022-01-01")}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would suggest using [`$dateFromParts`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/) to compare date for your scenario.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $lt: [
          "$date",
          {
            "$dateFromParts": {
              "year": 2022,
              "month": 2
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JLXm2Z9SGO9)

Comment: This works, just make sure in project stage to write this date: "$date", instead of        year: { $year: "$date" },
      month: { $month: "$date" },